# Non-integrable Lipschitz functions?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Are there Lipschitz continuous functions that are not in $L^{1}(\mu)$?

I understand that if $\mu$ was the Lebesgue measure, then certainly there would be nonintegrable Lipschitz functions. for example the function $f(x) = x$ is Lipschitz but is not integrable, since $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|x|dx = \infty$.

I can see that it suffices to have the function $x \mapsto |x|$ be integrable, since any Lipschitz function $f$ has $f(x) \leq f(0) + k|x|$ for some k.

I cannot grasp how $|x|$ could fail to be integrable w.r.t a probability measure. I would appreciate an example!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example: Let $\mu$ be the measure with density

$$h(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}\cdot \chi_{[1,+\infty)}(x)$$

with respect to the Lebesgue measure. It is easily checked that $\mu$ is a Borel probability measure. But

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lvert x\rvert\,d\mu(x) = \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{x}{x^2}\,dx = \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{x} = +\infty.$$

Comment: You misunderstand. $h$ is the density of the probability measure $\mu$. We have $$\mu(A) = \int_A h(x)\,dx$$ for all Borel (or, slightly more general, Lebesgue measurable) sets $A\subset \mathbb{R}$. Then we have a Lipschitz function - namely $x \mapsto \lvert x\rvert$ - that is not integrable wrt. $\mu$.